# Why Google Chrome run multiple processes when there is single tab opened?

Tags: google-chrome, windows-7

It is logical to run multiple processes when multiple tabs are there but in my  Google Chrome i found multiple processes under single tab only. I thought it was some thread stuck so i restarted my PC and opened Google Chrome only and found same behavior. I am using Windows 7.

[image: Screenshot]

Answer (score 1):

Chrome has plugins, web apps, rendering engines and others as separate processes from the browser itself.

That is done so that if one of those processes fails, it won't affect the whole browser, or even the whole tab, because those are separate processes too.

For example, Firefox doesn't have that, instead it detects the script in the page that should be causing the problem and shows you a dialog for if you want to stop it.

## In summary:

Chrome treats these as different processes:

- The browser
- The browser (yes, again. Chrome by itself it's already 2 processes)
- Each tab
- Each extension (at **least** one per extension)
- Each web app
- Each plugin
- **Each whatever, everybody is a process, *yay!***

And that helps things can run in parallel and that that stuff doesn't end up crashing the whole browser.

Answer (score 0):

Less crashes or at least when a process crash not all the browser crash, increase security, to make things run in parallel

> Google Chrome takes advantage of these properties and puts web apps and plug-ins in separate processes from the browser itself. This means that a rendering engine crash in one web app won’t affect the browser or other web apps. It means the OS can run web apps in parallel to increase their responsiveness, and it means the browser itself won’t lock up if a particular web app or plug-in stops responding. It also means we can run the rendering engine processes in a restrictive sandbox that helps limit the damage if an exploit does occur.In this world, browsers that put everything in one process face real challenges for robustness, responsiveness, and security.  If one web app causes a crash in the rendering engine, it will take the rest of the browser with it, including any other web apps that are open.  Web apps often have to compete with each other for CPU time on a single thread, sometimes causing the entire browser to become unresponsive.  Security is also a concern, because a web page that exploits a vulnerability in the rendering engine can often take over your entire computer.

https://www.howtogeek.com/124218/why-does-chrome-have-so-many-open-processes/

> On top of this, the parts of the browser that render HTML, JavaScript, and CSS have become extraordinarily complex over time.  These rendering engines frequently have bugs as they continue to evolve, and some of these bugs may cause the rendering engine to occasionally crash.  Also, rendering engines routinely face untrusted and even malicious code from the web, which may try to exploit these bugs to install malware on your computer.In this world, browsers that put everything in one process face real challenges for robustness, responsiveness, and security.  If one web app causes a crash in the rendering engine, it will take the rest of the browser with it, including any other web apps that are open.  Web apps often have to compete with each other for CPU time on a single thread, sometimes causing the entire browser to become unresponsive.  Security is also a concern, because a web page that exploits a vulnerability in the rendering engine can often take over your entire computer.

https://blog.chromium.org/2008/09/multi-process-architecture.html

Comment: I know Chromium is an open source project for Chrome, and that it's were they release that kind of detail. What happens is that I thought that it's lazy to just write a little more than ten words (now twenty), and quote the rest, regardless of what you've read, it doesn't take much time to do that anyway... It was actually a suggestion you to improve your answer. But, whatever, it's your answer.